# How to send email notification to users few days before expiry date in alfresco

Tags: windows-10, alfresco

I want to send email notification to users say 'X' days prior to their document expiry date. How can it be achieved on alfresco 5.2 community and windows platform?

Comment: How are you storing the expiry date? Custom workflow? Built in workflow? Content property? Other?

Comment: content property

Comment: Custom scheduled job is probably the way then - see https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.1/develop/repo-ext-points/scheduled-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

You can create scheduled job which will run at specific time.

https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/5.2/develop/repo-ext-points/scheduled-jobs/

Within job write logic to get document which is going to expire within some time.

Ex.

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

SearchService searchService = serviceRegistry.getSearchService();
        SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
        searchParameters.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
        searchParameters.addStore(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
        
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().plusMonths(1);
        String date= now.format(DATE_FORMATTER); 
        String query=""
        searchParameters.setQuery(query);
        ResultSet rs =  searchService.query(searchParameters);
```

This will find document which is going to expire in next 1 month.